# "Hello" as a verb

Tags: verbs, word-usage, verbing

A dictionary says that Hello could be a **verb, noun and interjection**. I'm not sure I saw it to be a verb though.

Q: Could someone provide an example of 'hello' where it's used **as verb**. In the meaning of its synonym phrase 'say hello'.

Can I say for example: "I hello you?" (Probably not but what can I *hello*?)

Comment: I was just about to closevote as General Reference, but I see you've edited to include the fact that you saw "hello" defined as a verb *in a dictionary*. Now I'm really intrigued. What dictionary?

Comment: Well, there is a dictionary (there is #3 meaning is a verb). I'm sure it is not the only one that has it. http://www.lingvo-online.ru/en/Translate/en-ru/hello

Comment: @Susan: Good grief! Well, [here are examples of *"**to goodbye**"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22we+goodbyed%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (used both transitively and intransitively). As Reg says, *any* word can be used as a verb. But I really can't see much point in dictionaries listing every word as, *inter alia*, a "verb".

Comment: As Calvin says to Hobbes, "Verbing weirds language".

Comment: Oh hello, what’s this interjection bit?

Comment: [TFD: Hallo](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hallo) may be of interest, pointing to a Hello-Hallo-Halloo connection.

Comment: You can hello yourself and see how you like it.

Answer (score 20):

Theoretically, any, absolutely any word in English can be used as a verb. Nothing prevents you from helloing, betweening, egadsing or greating.

However, it's one thing to just use a word as a verb, but a different thing altogether to have it also be *understood* by others, and it's a different thing still for it to also be perfectly natural and unexceptionable. That is what language is all about, after all: communication. And as Calvin of *Calvin and Hobbes* famously put it, "verbing weirds language".

So yes, "I hello you" is a perfectly grammatical English sentence, but it is also a perfectly unidiomatic one. Perhaps not quite as nonsensical as the textbook example ["colorless green ideas sleep furiously"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously) — but at best, you might get away with it as a joke, or an otherwise deliberate attempt at unusualness, and at worst, people will just think you are a non-native speaker who could use better command of the language.

A native speaker is much more likely to produce "I greet you". Though that one has problems of its own, so actually just the greeting itself — "hello", or "greetings", or "welcome", or "top of the morning to you", or what have you — would be more common still.

Comment: Ok. Thanks I like this theoretical approach. I just thought though if dictionary has it, it refers to some legal usage, otherwise all words could come with 'V' mark.

Comment: In *The Hobbit*, Tolkien wrote when Bilbo tried to get rid of Gandalf with a good morning: “To think that I should have lived to be goodmorninged by Belladonna Took's son, as if I was selling buttons at the door!”  Curiously, in the movie, either the writers or Ian McKellen himself altered the original rustic *was* to the more primly *were*, perhaps to avoid grating on the North American ear.

Comment: Why only NA ears? "as if I were" sounds better to my ears too that "as if I was" - Is the were not correct in BE?

Comment: Bring it on! :)

Comment: @mplungjan No dearth of mirth bring brought forth.

Comment: Not a huge difference between BE/AE in [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+if+I+were%2Cas+if+I+was&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20if%20I%20were%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20if%20I%20was%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: This process is commonly known as ['zero-derivation' or 'conversion'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation)). It is particularly productive in English.

Comment: Amusingly the "classic" example is [steadily gaining meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environmentally_friendly)

Comment: @ses: your usage of "legal" above seems to imply that you think there is some authority which rules on what is a word and what isn't. **There is no such authority**

Answer (score 13):

Other answers have argued for *hello*'s capacity to be a verb (but seem to doubt that it actually *is* a verb). I'll leave them the theory, here are recent examples of its use.

> Stein had walked nodding and helloing straight to the bar and leaning on its structure of crates ordered a drink. (Thin Red Line)
>
> He was just helloing me like I was his long-lost tich uncle. (Hockey Sur Glace)
>
> I helloed to the boys to circle around on the other side of the canyon. (Wells, Fargo and Co Stagecoach and Robberies)
>
> Walter helloed again, slammed the door to his truck and leaned against it. (The Coldest Night)

It seems to be especially common in poetry and westerns

Comment: Great datamining work.

Comment: Could one understand from this that you hello *to* somebody, making the *Hockey sur Glace* example incorrect?

Comment: ngrams certainly indicates that youre right https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=helloed+to%2Bhelloes+to%2Bhelloing+to%2Chelloed%2Bhelloing%2Bhelloes&year_start=1880&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28helloed%20to%20%2B%20helloes%20to%20%2B%20helloing%20to%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28helloed%20%2B%20helloing%20%2B%20helloes%29%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 3):

You can **[greet](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+greet&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)** someone; you can **bid** someone **hello**; you can acknowledge someone.

You are correct that the dictionary lists **hello** as a **verb**:

> verb: hello; 3rd person present: helloes; past tense: helloed; past participle: helloed; gerund or present participle: helloing; verb: hallo; 3rd person present: halloes; past tense: halloed; past participle: halloed; gerund or present participle: halloing; verb: hullo; 3rd person present: hulloes; past tense: hulloed; past participle: hulloed; gerund or present participle: hulloing
>   1. say or shout “hello”; greet someone.

but I would say this would be strange in AmE.

Answer (score 2):

Almost any word can be a verb. Probably the best examples to demonstrate this are expressions to express intoxication:

> I was hammered
>   I got absolutely roof-topped

Or, to some examples of a British stand-up comedian:

> I got utterly gazebo-ed, Completely bungalowed

Yes, you can indeed get *"so ladle'd"* and provided you say it in the right way (hint: emphasize the past participle), everyone will know what you're on about. Be careful, though, because some nouns have a rather specific, and sometimes deviant meaning when used as a verb (Teabag, scissor, spoon...)

I can imagine my using *hello* as a verb in certain cases, to convey a certain image/feeling:

> All he did was helloing the guests, but refused to lend a helping hand.

Or, if I were to tell you of some formal happening where I felt as the odd one out, I might say something like

> I helloed a couple of people, but I felt like a right git doing so

With this, I'd hope to conjure up an image of me, standing in a corridor, with a rented tuxedo that doesn't quite fit, being nervous and hoping to be able to sneak out ASAP.

However, I'd say *"hello"* is quite commonly used as a gerund, which is a *verb* used as a noun.
So you might think of the following sentence as a word, commonly used as a noun, being used as a verb, that is in turn being used as a noun again:

> Your helloing everyone was a sight to behold

Then again, you're more likely to say:

> [You] saying your hellos was a sight to behold

Answer (score 1):

It is more likely used in the past tense, in the sense of greeting, wishing, hailing or just plain interrupting someone (esp., in the passing), analogous to *Hi'ed* (informal/ teen lingo). ="said 'Hello'".

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/helloed)

> *intr.v.* hel·loed, hel·lo·ing, hel·loes
>   To call "hello."

[DRC](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/helloed?r=66)

> *verb (used without object)*, hel·loed, hel·lo·ing.
>   **5**. to say “hello”; to cry or shout: *I helloed, but no one answered.*

---

Some related quotes appear in the answer by user @Unrelated on this page!

Comment: I believe the past tenses of both *hi* and *hie* are regular, and thus converge upon a common *hied* for that inflection.